# I try to test IOS IN APP sandbox to payment

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox

Testing the payment of IOS IN APP
However, 'Now in the sandbox are not certified for In App purchase' the
alert popup ...

How do I solve? Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure your testing on a device and not in the Simulator.

Next, go to the App Store and sign out of your current account.

Then make the purchase in your app and it'll ask you to sign in, use your test account that you created in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Being practiced answers.
Failed in the simulator. the same result was also tried in the device.

Comment: Have you added a provisioning profile for the app instead of the standard dev one?

Comment: I have One ad_hoc provisioning profile and one dev provisioning profile.

Comment: was to achive ad_hoc provisioning profile.

Comment: And the dev one is app specific and not the general one. You added In Apps to iTunes Connect and set up a test user?